# How to use AUTO_INCREMENT=value in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I am creating simple table like below, But I am getting below error. I search in net, but I am not able to find error.  I am just trying to use `AUTO_INCREMENT=201`.

```
CREATE TABLE `address` (
  `id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT=201,
  `kkk` varchar(3) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`account_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=606 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '= 201,   `kkk` varchar(3) NOT NULL,    PRIMARY KEY (`account_id`) ) ENGINE=InnoD' at line 2    0.000 sec

Answer (score 1):

The `auto_increment` option is a table option, not a column option.  Hence, it goes at the end of the `create table` statement or in a separate `alter table` statement:

```
CREATE TABLE `address` (
  `id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `jjj` varchar(3) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`account_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=201 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below Query :

```
CREATE TABLE `address` (
  `id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `kkk` varchar(3) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=606 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below

```
CREATE TABLE `address` (
  `id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `kkk` varchar(3) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=201 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```